# How can I run a remote open space?

Tags: moderators, communication

I have participated in several open space events at technical conferences, and I found them to be effective for getting people to loosen up and learn and contribute.

I conduct frequent technical sessions in my organization, and I thought it would be useful to try this format. Unfortunately 60% of the participants log in via [WebEx](https://www.webex.com/).

It seems like it should be doable, although [the law of two feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Space_Technology#Law_of_two_feet) might be a challenge.

Has anyone ever run an open space event successfully over a web meeting?
What did you do to make it successful?

More on open spaces here: [Doing an open space: a two page primer](http://www.openspaceworld.org/files/tmnfiles/2pageos.htm)

Comment: Very interested in this; I've tried to run an open space with a few remote participants, and it was a failure and decided not to every try it again.

Comment: how does an "open space" vary from a "hackathon"?

Comment: @warren An open space is usually a short discussion session, 1 hour at most. Hackathons are generally about collaborating on a coding effort, and can last 1/2 day to 1 full day